# Mounting a VHDX ext4 partition in linux

Tags: linux, mount, ext4, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm wondering how terrible an idea the following is or is not...

I want to share an ext4 fs between WSL2 and linux using a fixed-size .vhdx image created in windows (residing on NTFS partition). Mounting this in WSL is straightforward, but the issue I am trying to avoid is a bunch of FUSE or NBD overhead accessing the drive in native linux.

No problems mounting the ntfs (mounted as ntfs3) partition, but to get to my question: is there any reason it is a bad idea to directly mount the ext4 partition that lives in the .vhdx file? I.E:

```
mount -o offset=5MiB /mnt/<ntfs_partition>/ext4.vhdx <mount_point>
```

It seems to work fine... for now.

Comment: The important question here is whether VHDX format is a linear range of blocks that contain the entire ext4 partition, or whether the ext4 filesystem is a "file" or "logical volume" that may be non-contiguous within the larger container?  If VHDX is just a full disk image (including partition table), then it should be OK as long as *only one mount* is done at a time. Also, you can only mount the same ext4 filesystem from two hosts at the same time if they are both readonly mounts.  Mounting one read-write and the other read-only is not safe.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen any evidence of block re-ordering in the VHDX file yet, and I definitely wouldn't try this on a dynamic volume. Also, note that between windows and WSL, the volume is only allowed to be owned by one or the other at any given time (via wsl --mount / --unmount), and It is being accessed as designed in WSL (vhdx mounted properly). I am only testing out this questionable mounting mechanism in a native linux boot up.

Comment: A quick skim through [the specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-vhdx/83e061f8-f6e2-4de1-91bd-5d518a43d477) suggests it is possible for blocks to be unallocated within the image

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to routinely mount a non-parallel filesystem on different hosts. As long as the access is exclusive, this is fine, but one accident and you'll end up with a lot of corruption.

If it were me, I'd have access mediated by a specific host - and since MS-Wnidows needs to be running anyway, that is the obvious candidate. Unless you EXPLICITLY require this to be ext4 formated, I'd use a native directory accessed via drvfs from WSL and SMB from the VM.